# How to get attribute value of node in xml using xpath in javascript

Tags: sharepoint, xpath

Hi I am trying to get the user profile properties from sharepoint on client side with javascript.But I am not getting the  value of nodes in xml.
How to get them. the xml will look like as:

How to get attribute value of node in xml using xpath

Here I want to get the value which is between `<name>` tags `<Name>AccountName</Name>` and between **Name** tags

want to get the value = abc what will be the xpath expression

Please help

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetUserProfileByNameResponse xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService">
      <GetUserProfileByNameResult>
        <Pro pertyData>
          <IsPrivacyChanged>false</IsPrivacyChanged>
          <IsValueChanged>false</IsValueChanged>
          <Name>UserProfile_GUID</N ame>
            <Privacy>NotSet</Privacy>
            <Values>
              <ValueData>
                <Value xmlns:q1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/" xsi:type="q1:guid">8ed84415-7330-4857-a7d2- d797d71c439f

                </Value>
              </ValueData>
            </Values>
            </PropertyData>
            <PropertyData>
              <IsPrivacyChanged>false</IsPrivacyChanged>
              <Is ValueChanged>false</IsValueChanged>
                <Name>AccountName</Name>
                <Privacy>NotSet</Privacy>
                <Values>
                  <ValueData>
                    <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">abc

                    </Value>
                  </ValueData>
                </Values>
            </PropertyData>
      </GetUserProfileByNameResult>
    </GetUserProfileByNameResponse>
    </ soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: Post some javascript showing what have you tried so far..

Answer (score 1):

```
var propertyData = $(responseXML).find("PropertyData").filter(function(e){
    return $(this).find("Name").text() == "AccountName";
});
var value = propertyData.length > 0 ? propertyData.find('Value').text() : '';
```

---

Since you are trying to retrieve user profile via SharePoint Web Services I would recommend to utilize [SPServices library](https://spservices.codeplex.com/), it hides (almost)all the intricacies when working with *SharePoint Web Services* from JavaScript. The following example demonstrates how to retrieve user profile using [GetUserProfileByName method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcuserprofileservice.userprofileservice.getuserprofilebyname.aspx) and process the results:

```
function getUserProfile(accountName,completeFn) {
  var userInfo = {};
  $().SPServices({
    AccountName: accountName,  
    operation: 'GetUserProfileByName',
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").each(function() {
        userInfo[$(this).find("Name").text()] = $(this).find("Value").text();
      }); 
      completeFn(userInfo);
    }
  });
}

var loginName = 'i:0#.f|membership|username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com';
getUserProfile(loginName,function(info){
    console.log(info);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to traverse through the xml nodes returned from the SPServices. I have written a function for getting the desired user profile property.

```
function getUPValue(x, p) {  
   var thisValue = $(x).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").filter(function() {  
     return $(this).find("Name").text() == p;  
   }).find("Values").text();  
   return thisValue;  
 }
```

Further to query the user property you just need to call like below,

```
getUPValue(xData.responseXML, "WorkEmail");
```

These article provides a detail overview of it over [here](http://kalashnikovtechnoblogs.blogspot.in/2015/09/query-user-profile-service-for-multiple.html)